# Exit, reset, or clear JavaScript call stack without throw Error?

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise, react-native-navigation, callstack

Given a number of nested promises structured similarly to the example below, is it possible, given a `timeout` result in `delta()` to neither `return`, `resolve`, nor `reject` the `timeout`, and not `throw Error(timeout)`, but somehow exit the JavaScript call stack and reset to a new screen?

- Context is React Native app
- Nav library is react-native-navigation
- Goal is to not `throw Error(timeout)`
- We do not want the error to bubble up through the promise chain
- The promise nesting occurs in unique variations in 100s of places in the app
- We do not want individually handle a `timeout` response/error in each spot
- Hoping instead to somehow exit the call stack and reset the screen
- react-native-navigation has a slew of methods to `setRoot`, `navigateToScreen`, etc, but these don't exit call stack

```js
const alpha = async () => {
  try return await bravo()
  catch (e) throw Error(e)
}

const bravo = async () => {
  try return await charlie()
  catch (e) throw Error(e)
}

const charlie = async () => {
  try return await delta()
  catch (e) throw Error(e)
}

const delta = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await API()
    if (res === timeout) // clearCallStackAndResetToNewScreenDoNotThrowError() POSSIBLE?
    else return res
  } catch (e) {
    throw Error(e)
  }
}

const one = async () => {
  try {
    await alpha()
  } catch (e) {
    uniqueErrorHandling(e)
  }
}

const two = async () => {
  try {
    await alpha()
  } catch (e) {
    uniqueErrorHandling(e)
  }
}

one()
two()
etc ...
```

Comment: If you don't want to throw an exception, the only way to signal the timeout condition is to handle it explicitly everywhere, e.g. with `if` statements.

Comment: `catch (e) throw Error(e)` doesn't make much sense. You should completely omit the `try` if you cannot actually handle the error.

Comment: Yeah I'm afraid explicit handling of the timeout is the only option at this point